# How to catch new window opend by window.open(url, _blank) in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, window.open

I'd like to check with PhantomJS whether my script correctly opens a new window/tab on click. The open is triggerd by a js event listener and opened through `window.open(url, "_blank")`.

How can I listen for the new window with PhantomJS?

Comment: Just checkt it as right with my phone to close the question. It was 3am saturday morning in germany and i havent checked the answer yet :')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There seem to be three ways to do this:

### onPageCreated

CasperJS solves this by using [`page.onPageCreated`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-page-created.html). So when `window.open` is called in the page, a new page is created and `page.onPageCreated` is triggered with the newly created page.

```
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        page.onPageCreated = function(newPage){
            newPage.onLoadFinished = function(){
                console.log(newPage.url);
                phantom.exit();
            };
        };
        page.evaluate(function(url){
            window.open(url+"?something=other", "_blank");
        }, address);
    }
})
```

### pages

PhantomJS' `page` has a [`pages`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/pages.html) property which handles of the child pages. So, when you `open` a new page/tab, a new `webpage` object is created for that page. You need to try to add an `onLoadFinished` event listener to the page before it fires (no promises). It can be hard and when the `window.open` is called with an unknown delay from the page context.

This can be fixed by using something like [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait for the new page to appear and attach the event handler before the page is loaded. Here is the complete code with a small adjustment. The retry interval is reduced to 50ms from 250ms.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var address = "http://example.com/";

function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000, //< Default Max Timout is 3s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 50); //< repeat check every 50ms
};

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        console.log("p:", page.ownsPages, typeof page.pages, page.pages.length, page.pages);
        waitFor(function test(){
            return page.pages && page.pages[0];
        }, function ready(){
            page.pages[0].onLoadFinished = function(){
                console.log("p:", page.ownsPages, typeof page.pages, page.pages.length, page.pages);
                console.log("inner:", page.pages[0].url);
                phantom.exit();
            };
        });
        page.evaluate(function(url){
            window.open(url+"?something=other", "_blank");
        }, address);
    }
})
```

### Proxy solution

The `window.open` function can be proxied and after the opening the page in the page context, an event handler can be registered in phantom context signaled through `window.callPhantom` and caught in [`onCallback`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html).

```
page.onInitialized = function(){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        var _oldOpen = window.open;
        window.open = function(url, type){
            _oldOpen.call(window, url, type);
            window.callPhantom({type: "open"});
        };
    });
};
page.onCallback = function(data){
    // a little delay might be necessary
    if (data.type === "open" && page.pages.length > 0) {
        var newPage = page.pages[page.pages.length-1];
        newPage.onLoadFinished = function(){
            console.log(newPage.url);
            phantom.exit();
        };
    }
};
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        page.evaluate(function(url){
            window.open(url+"?something=other", "_blank");
        }, address);
    }
})
```

Comment: I am using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriver from C#.  Is it possible to do something similar in .NET?

Comment: @fireydude You try to use those three solutions through the `PhantomJSDriver.ExecutePhantomJS` method, but I don't know if it will work. I also don't know if it is possible to do this otherwise. Ask a new question and see if somebody has an answer.