# Phantomjs as Client: Handle new tab

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

A quite similar case is handled [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980178/how-to-catch-new-window-opend-by-window-openurl-blank-in-phantomjs/27981193#27981193) but here the problem is focused using Phantomjs as server.

My problem is, that I use Phantomjs as client. During my code is executed a new
tab is opened. At the moment I handle this the following way. Here is the first initialization of the `WebPage:`

```
var page = new WebPage();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
};

page.onUrlChanged = function(targetUrl) {
    console.log('New URL: ' + targetUrl);
};
```

Now to handle the second page I implemented the `onPageCreated` handler like this:

```
page.onPageCreated = function(new_page){
    new_page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
      logger.log(msg);
    };

    new_page.onLoadStarted = function() {
      loadInProgress = true;
    };

    new_page.onLoadFinished = function() {
      loadInProgress = false;

    };
    page = new_page;
};
```

The problem is, that this of course only works once, because the new page assigned to the old one does not implement the `onPageCreated` method again.

**Question:**
Is there some way to do this in a different more elegant way? I saw in the documentation, that there is a property called `pages` but the documentation is quite bad there. Is it possible to just switch my main frame on which I am working to this new tab and close the old tab without changing the whole page element like I do at the moment?

Something like (pseudocode)

```
page.onPageCreated = function(new_page){
    //page.mainFrame = new_page.mainFrame;
    //or
    //page.goToNextTab();
}
```

**Additional Question**
An additional problem is, that it does not seem to work, if I just initialize my page again, like I did in the first code snippet. It seems to me like there is something garbage collected while it should not be garbage collected.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using PhantomJS as client or as server. The linked question has a similar use case as you. PhantomJS has a webserver module which is not used at all in the linked question.

Comment: Ok thanks. My actual version just exits the script and restarts it again. Wrapped it into a shell script.

Comment: With client I mean, that I run the script on my machine and it accesses a webpage and does some stuff automatically.